# Multiple API calls

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to call multiple APIs and get the result of all the APIs in a single list.
I have thought for looping and then get the APIs call one by one but struct in between.
Can anyone help me in this because after getting the result in form of a list .I have to use that list to draw a pie chart.

```
Future<List<int>> status() async {
   var data = new http.Client();
     String basicAuth =
    'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
List<String> itemsIds = ['new', 'open', 'stalled', 'resolved']; 

return Future.wait<>(['new', 'open', 'stalled', 'resolved'].map((item) =>
data.get(Uri.encodeFull("sampleapi'and(status='$item')/" + '/next'),headers:{'authorization': basicAuth}.then((response) {

  })
)
);
```

}

Comment: What is not working? `Future.wait<>` looks good, you just should provide a type between `<>` or remove `<>` alltogether.

Comment: No its not working.

Comment: I want an example for the same with real code.